# Automatic timestamp when 2 cell is filled out

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

Google Sheet Apps Script

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const editedRange = e.range
  const sheet = editedRange.getSheet()
  if (
    sheet.getName() === 'Data' &&
    editedRange.getLastColumn() >= 5 /*E*/ &&
    editedRange.getColumn() <= 6 /*F*/
  ) {
    const timestampRange = sheet.getRange(editedRange.getRow(), 1, editedRange.getNumRows(), 1)
    timestampRange.setValue(new Date())
  }
}
```

When E&F is Filled then A is Time Stamp

but i get *TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
onEdit  @ Code.gs:2*

Comment: share your input data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined onEdit @ Code.gs:2` means that there is no event object e from the range or it is failing. This is because you are running the script directly on the script editor.
[image]

The trigger **onEdit(e)** can't be run from the script editor as it requires an event object that is only being created upon making edits on the Spreadsheet. It is running automatically every time you change the value of a cell. See [onEdit(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) for more information.

To test your script you have to edit a cell then check the execution logs by clicking the Executions Tab on the menu on the left.

[image]

I have tested your script and it is running without an error. However, according to the condition you've stated it is supposed to only put timestamp when both E & F are filled so I have tweaked the code a bit to work according to this.

**Try:**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const editedRange = e.range
  const sheet = editedRange.getSheet()
  var row = editedRange.getRow();

  if (
    sheet.getName() === 'Data' &&
    (editedRange.getColumn() == 5 || editedRange.getColumn() == 6) &&
    (sheet.getRange(row, 5).getValue() !== "" && sheet.getRange(row, 6).getValue() !=="")
  ) {
    const timestampRange = sheet.getRange(editedRange.getRow(), 1, editedRange.getNumRows(), 1)
    timestampRange.setValue(new Date())
  }
}
```

**Result:**
[image]

Comment: Thankyou a lot Dan, i didnt check it thanks to you my script is running and also thank for the code too <3 its better than mine

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Glad to know your concern is resolved. As a general rule in StackOverflow, if your concern is solved please accept an answer which works best for you by clicking the check mark beside the answer. This is to let other members from the community with the same concern as yours know that the issue resolved. [How to accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).